# Why is my function skipping the else statement?

Tags: python

```
def pi_euler2(n):
    pi=[1,2]
    if n==1:
        return 1
    if n==2:
        two=sum([x**-1 for x in pi])
        return two
    for i in range(3,n+1):
        if isprime(i)==True:
            if (i+1)%4==0:
                i=abs(i)
                pi.append(i)
            if (i-1)%4==0:
                pi.append(i*-1)
        else:
            for j in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
                if isinstance(i/j,int)==True:
                    k=i/j
                    print(k)
                    pi.append((pi[j-1])*pi[k-1])
    return pi
```

I am trying to make a python program which estimates the value of pi by making it do an infinite series (up to length n). But the problem with my code is that for some reason it skips over the else statement (for when the number is not prime).

The problem is part of this section of the code

```
for i in range(3,n+1):
        if isprime(i)==True:
            if (i+1)%4==0:
                i=abs(i)
                pi.append(i)
            if (i-1)%4==0:
                pi.append(i*-1)
        else:
            for j in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
                if isinstance(i/j,int)==True:
                    k=i/j
                    print(k)
                    pi.append((pi[j-1])*pi[k-1])
```

The output only ever consists of prime numbers (e.g pi_euler2(50) outputs [1, 2, 3, -5, 7, 11, -13, -17, 19, 23, -29, 31, -37, -41, 43, 47])

The isprime function is

```
def isprime(n):
    for j in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%j == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: And you're sure that `isprime` is working for all values you pass to it? Please try to minimize the "input" set (if possible to only one of a couple of values), then use a debugger to see what happens and what your `isprime` function is returning (and doing).

Comment: I tried isprime and pi_euler2 for 1-10 and the isprime is working correctly (False for non prime, True for primes) but pi_euler2 follows the same list (but less elements up to the next number in the list) where it adds prime numbers to the list but not non primes.

Comment: isinstance(i/j,int)==True this condition is always False.

Answer (score 0):

the problem isn't with else part of your code, it works every time. the problematic part of your code is: `isinstance(i/j,int)`

every time you divide 2 numbers in python, it gives you a decimal number like 9/3 isn't just 3. the output is 3.0
so the isinstance() gives false every time. hence no append in pi.

you can try to use `if(i%j == 0)`.

then the if in j loop becomes:
`if i%j==0: k=int(i/j) ...`
and the output for 10 in your function comes out to be:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -10]` try and correct that

Answer (score 0):

Also, your `isprime` function seems to be incomplete. It should look something like this.

```
def isprime(n):
if n < 2:
    return False
for j in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
    if n % j == 0:
        return False
return True
```

You could probably just use already-provided prime checking functions (libraries such as mpmath, sympy, etc. include this functionality) which could do the job more accurately and efficiently.